# Website is not updating in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8

we're experiencing a very strange issue here where our web application is not updating.  Our application is built on ASP MVC Core 2 and hosted on Windows IIS 8.5.  When we initially hosted our web app everything worked just fine, however, the issue is when we tried to make any change/update to the web app after creation the changes did not appear on our website.

For example, if we changed the html div somewhere on the login page from "Please login" to "Some other message" it will still show "Please login".

We looked into browser caching and that is definitely not the issue.  We looked into output caching in IIS and it's not that either; there are no settings or rules that have been defined.  Could there be a setting application side that we're missing that's causing this strange behavior?  There didn't seem to be anything in the web.config file that can appear to be causing this problem.  We are at a complete loss and any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.